# MeshNormalMaterial color

Tags: three.js, shader, mesh, fragment-shader

In default MeshNormalMaterial example, the color of cube wall is changing because it uses this `THREE.ShaderLib[ 'normal' ]` shader. This shader sets `gl_FragColor` by this `gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.5 * normalize( vNormal ) + 0.5, opacity );`. Can anyone explain me this formula? which vector of cube is normalized? Are there any other factors that have impact on color?

http://www.smartjava.org/ltjs/chapter-04/04-mesh-normal-material.html - example

Sorry for stupid question, I'm new in three.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MeshNormalMaterial` basically colors an object based on its normals. So in the equation you gave `vNormal` is the vertex normal of that fragment. Think of it as translating the (x,y,z) vector of a normal to an (r,g,b) color. The transformation between the two spaces is given by that formula. if you had

```
gl_FragColor = vec4( vNormal, opacity );
```

then the final fragment color (i.e. the r,g,b,a values) would only depend on the normal.

In the equation you posted there is a constant term and half the normalized normal.

Comment: Okay I get it. But I have another question, How can I print gl_FragColor value of every frame for example in console. Where can I do it?

Comment: you cannot print to the console from a shader. a shader executes on the GPU. but both chrome and firefox have shader editor resources under their development tools.

Comment: I tried this, but how to get value of gl_FragColor?